# Session data not saved on disk and also when processing another page

Tags: php, session-cookies

I am trying to process simple HTML form when on submit `page1.php` is called.  `page1.php` internally calls `page2.php`

page1.php looks like this:

```
<?php 

session_start(); 
$sesid = session_id();
$_SESSION['cname'] = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['companyname'])); 
$_SESSION['fname'] = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['firstname'])); 
$_SESSION['lname'] = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['lastname'])); 
$_SESSION['eaddr']  = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['eaddress'])); 

echo " $_SESSION[cname]" ;
echo " $_SESSION[otprdsvc]";

include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/appconnector.php';

?>
```

Page2.php looks like this:

```
<?php

echo "$_SESSION[cname]";

?>
```

I do get output of echo `$_SESSION[cname];` on first page.  However, data is not saved to disk when I check session cookie.

Here is data from session cookie on disk:

```
  cname|s:0:"";fname|s:0:"";lname|s:0:"";eaddr|s:0:"";webaddr|N;cmsg|s:0:"";drpopt|N;otprdsvc|s:0:"";securimage_code_disp|a:1:{s:7:"default";s:6:"n55Zmr";}securimage_code_value|a:1:{s:7:"default";s:6:"n55zmr";}securimage_code_ctime|a:1:{s:7:"default";i:1398221627;}
```

I don't understand why `cname` is coming as "" ( no data / null ) where in fact I am getting response.

Little bit of history what I have done till now

- session.save_path was not enabled earlier in `php.ini` file so I enabled it.
- I was using `autocomplete = off` in html form earlier so I removed it.

securimage is packaged solution I am using for captcha which is saving cookie data but I don't know+understand anything what it did internally.

Can you please suggest what needs to be done in order to have session cookie data:

1. saved & available on disk in file
2. make it available when page2 is processed.

Thank you in advance and I apprecriate your time and comments.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to always do `session_start();` on every page before using the `$_SESSION` variable.

So page2 will be

```
<?php
   session_start();
   echo "$_SESSION[cname]" ;
?>
```

Comment: sorry , I had not typed it here on SO but I do have it in my code. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

For page1.php

```
....
    echo $_SESSION['cname'];
    echo $_SESSION['otprdsvc'];
....
```

For page2.php

```
<?php

  session_start();
  echo $_SESSION['cname'];

?>
```

You have to use session_start() on every page wherever you want to call the session data.

Comment: unfortunately this did not work.  I still don't know why cookie data is not written for all fields shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. Page2.php was submitting itself so session data was getting lost. I now have modified flow of data processing. I also used session.write_close() after writing data to session variables on page1.php so that also helped.

Thank you for your comments.